# How can we describe the trajectory of an object projected into a viscous fluid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Can we quantitatively describe the motion of a particle inside a fluid?

Let us consider the case when an object (say a sphere, so that stoke's law holds true) is projected into a fluid of viscosity $\mu$, with a velocity $v$,
at an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal.

I myself approached it through Newtonian mechanics. First off the problem is when the object enters the fluid. The buoyant force as well as the viscous force are varying. There will be some threshold velocity for which it enters the fluid. Let's assume that $v$ given to the ball  is enough to take it into the fluid. But how do we describe the motion of the ball while it is midway into the fluid?

I tried writing the forces (Buoyant, Viscous and Gravitational) with respect to displacement and form some sort of a differential equation but it din't work for me.

So i skipped that part and considered that the ball has entered the fluid and has a velocity $v'$ and makes an angle $\phi$ with the horizontal. This part i think is simpler.

At an arbitrary time, i assumed the $x$ component of velocity to be $v_x$ and the $y$ component to be $v_y$.

$$\vec{F_x}=-6 \pi \eta r \vec{v_x}$$

&$$\vec{F_y}=-6 \pi \eta r \vec{v_y}+m\vec{g}+\vec{F_{B}}$$

I do not know what to do next. Help will be appreciated, in both the cases- first, when the ball is entering the fluid, and the second after entering the fluid.

Comment: Did you consider Newton's second law?

Comment: Yes..i did--> $\vec {F}=m\vec{a}=-6\pi\eta r \vec {v} +\vec{F_B}+m\vec{g}$.

Comment: You may be interested in multi-fluid simulations, though I am not sure what references to give you, outside of doing a Google search.

Comment: The atmosphere is a viscous fluid, too!  Just pointing that out because you may want to consider which forces (viscosity, buoyancy, gravitational) are significant for the fluid of interest.